# Get back default /bin/bash

Tags: bash, shortcuts, xterm

After installing virtualbox + few upgrades I found that I have no longer my default bash, but now I have (probably) xterm. (there was also problem with unity, but I coped with it). I can not execute /bin/bash from doubleclick on it in folder, but I "can execute" it from xterm console (however it doesnt open new one, it just reload xterm session and nothing more).
How could I get back default ubuntu 14.04 bash console?

Moreover shortcut *alt+ctrl+t* stopped working (and creating new one which overwrittes and points to /bin/bash still didnt solve the problem). Clicking *alt+ctrl+t* just do nothing.

edit:

- I tried *apt-get install --reinstall bash* but it didn't help.
- when I execute "#!/bin/bash" script it runs in xterm window.

Comment: Note that XTerm is the emulator - Bash is still running inside that.  I think you're looking to run `gnome-terminal` though.

Comment: You're totally right! I do not know why, but it was uninstalled!...
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash still exists - it's not the terminal emulator.

`gnome-terminal` is the one the versions are supposed to use for Ubuntu, however when that gets removed or such it's possible that `xterm` is used in place.

Make sure that `gnome-terminal` is installed.